# Quero ao reconhecer o cpf na tabela, exibir uma pagina com outros dados. Onde estou errando?

Tags: php, select

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\solidario\associados.php on line 15

Meu codigo php

```
<?php

include"conectar.php";

// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÃ?RIO !
// $funct       = $_POST ["funct"]; //atribuiÃ§Ã£o do campo "nome" vindo do formulÃ¡rio para variavel   
$cpf = $_POST ["cpf"];  //atribuiÃ§Ã£o do campo "cpf" vindo do formulÃ¡rio para variavel

$query="select cpf from teste where cpf = '" . $cpf . "'";
        $stmt = mysqli_query( $con, $query);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( mysqli_error($con), true) );
}
else
    {$rows = mysql_num_rows($stmt);
     if ($rows === true) {
     include('index.php');}
      else
      {include('dr-adesao.php');}
    }  

mysqli_close( $con );
?>
```

Minha conexão está funcionando!

Acredito que o erro seja no arquivo *PHP*!

Comment: Leia [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579). Altere `$rows = mysql_num_rows($stmt);` para `$rows = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);`

Comment: fiz a alteração mas mesmo com o cpf já cadastrado na tabela, ainda me remete a pagina de tabela não afetada!

Comment: Vamos por passos, o erro foi corrigido ? Remove o espaço que tem na linha `$cpf = $_POST ["cpf"]` deixando assim `$cpf = $_POST["cpf"]`

Comment: sim corrigi, mas me mandou para .. else dr-adesao.php e como o cpf já está na tabela, deveria me enviar para index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque você esta utilizando o método antigo da extensão *MySQL* `mysql_num_rows` deve alterar para o novo método `mysqli_num_rows`.

---

O método `mysqli_num_rows` obtém a quantidade de linhas de um resultado e não um valor *Booleano*, deve alterar a linha:

```
if ($rows === true)
```

Para:

```
if ($rows === 1)
```

Ou

```
if ($rows > 0)
```

---

Remova o espaço que tem na linha

```
$cpf = $_POST ["cpf"];
             ^
$cpf = $_POST["cpf"]; // Deixe assim
```

---

Para retornar os dados você deve alterar sua *Query SQL* de:

```
$query="select cpf from teste where cpf = '" . $cpf . "'";
```

Para:

```
$query="select conlunaA, colunaB, colunaC from teste where cpf = '{$cpf}'";
```

Altere *colunaA, colunaB, colunaC* para o nome das colunas que contém sua tabela.

Comment: Obrigado wéllingthon! mas eu só tenho uma coluna e esta se chama cpf.

Comment: Entendi, é porque eu fui pelo titulo da pergunta.

Comment: deixa eu te perguntar, será que o erro esta no mysqli_num_rows?

Comment: bom vou tentar ser mais especifico... tenho um número de cpf na tabela, ao digitar na tela o numero da tabela essa tela me envia para uma tela demostrando o restante do cadastro!

Comment: Veja que você começou usando `mysqli_*` na hora que você está retornando o número de linhas que a `query` retornou você está usando `mysql_num_rows` creio que isso cause o problema, não tenho como testar agora.

Comment: eu já troquei está assim agora

Comment: <?php

include"conectar.php";

// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÃ?RIO !
// $funct     = $_POST ["funct"]; //atribuiÃ§Ã£o do campo "nome" vindo do formulÃ¡rio para variavel 
$cpf=$_POST["cpf"]; //atribuiÃ§Ã£o do campo "email" vindo do formulÃ¡rio para variavel

$query="select cpf from teste where cpf = '{$cpf}'";
  $stmt = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(mysqli_error($con), true) );
}
else
 {$rows = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
  if ($rows === true) {
  include('index.php');}
   else
   {include('dr-adesao.php');}
 }  


?>

Comment: Altere a linha `if ($rows === true)` para `if ($rows > 0)`

Comment: Wéllingthon muito obrigado! Me ajudou mesmo!